# ImportError in test files

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, pytest, importerror

I've seen a lot of questions that are similar to this but none of the solutions have worked for me. I'm getting an import error when trying to run pytest on a test package I'm developing to teach myself how to create python packages.

Currently I have a python package that looks like

```
MyPackage/
  - src/
    - modules/
        - __init__.py
        - module_a.py
  - tests/
    - test_module_a.py
```

and my `test_module_a.py` contains

```py
import pytest
from modules.module_a import MyClass

# ... some tests
```

Running the command `pytest` in the terminal displays

```sh
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/.../Desktop/MyPackage/tests/test_module_a.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
../../anaconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_module_a.py:2: in <module>
    from modules.module_a import MyClass
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules'
```

I've attempted to add the path through the pycharm interpreter but it hasn't fixed it. I've also seen ways that use the `sys` package to change the path in the test file, but I'm fairly certain there is a way to set up test to work in pycharm without it. Additionally I'd like to be prepared to setup automatic tests through github so figuring out a way that also integrates well with that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error didn't have anything to do with the environment. The tutorial I followed put a different name under `name` in `setup.cfg` than the module name, so setting that to match solved the problem.